# Cast value to array of unknown `Element` type

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

Assuming a function that operates on any `Array`:

```
func g<T>(array: [T]) -> Void {
  // ...
}
```

...and a function that receives a value of type `Any`:

```
func f(x: Any) -> Void {
  if x is Array {
    // g(?)
  }
}
```

How can I get a properly typed version of `x` that I can pass to `g`?

Note that `g` doesn't rely (explicitly) on the type `T`. All it needs is the ability to iterate over the elements, which can be treated as values of type `Any`. Any solution that rewrites `g` to remove the type parameter is therefore also acceptable.

**Edit**: to make things harder, I'd like this to work on Linux, where Swift arrays aren't `NSArray`s until you've called `.bridge()` on them.

Comment: It depends on how you using T in g function. T should go with a generic constraints such as T should implement a protocol or extends from an abstract class. It does not make sense If T has no constraints.

Comment: `g` is statically bound, `x.Element`  is dynamically retrieved, you can't combine them

Comment: @Loc I don't explicitly use `T` in `g`. Let's say I just print the length.

Comment: @Cristik since I don't explicitly use `T` in `g`, can I write a different, equivalent, signature for `g`?

Comment: You could declare the array as `NSArray` and remove the generic, this will however make you loose the type safety and force you to use only `Objective-C` objects within the array...

Comment: @Cristik good suggestion. Unfortunately, an additional problem is that I want to run this on Linux. To pass a Swift array as `NSArray` on Linux you need to call `bridge()`, and I can only call it if I have a properly typed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning** Please note that the below results are based on my experiments on `Mirror` and work in Swift 2.1.1 (Xcode 7.1.1). It might be that future Swift versions will change the `Mirror` behaviour.

If finding out dynamically if the value is an array of any type, you could use Swift's reflection support, via the [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) struct:

```
func processArray(array: Any) -> Bool {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: array)
    guard mirror.displayStyle == .Collection else {
        return false
    }

    print("array has \(mirror.children.count) elements")

    return true
}

func f(x: Any) {
    if processArray(x) {
        // i just found an array
    }
}

f([1, 2, 3, "4"]) // prints "array has 4 elements"
```

Comment: This, this is the most satisfying solution I've seen!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the generic, you could do this instead:

```
func g<T>(array: [T]) -> Void {

}

func f(x: Any) -> Void {
    if let array = x as? [Any] {
        g(array)
    }
}
```